# Different types of font python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts

Is there a way to make different types of font in python three?
I need to make print statements monospace font and input statements boldface, blue, underlined characters.

Comment: Python just prints to your console or terminal. What platform are you on? What terminal or console are you using?

Comment: I am using WingIDE 101 (the free one)

Comment: You probably want something like [IPython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html). OTOH you may want to generate HTML or something like that

Comment: @KiraShelton: You cannot set text properties in the WingIDE console, no.

Comment: Apparently my friend managed to do it except for the boldface...

Comment: Are you talking about print and input expressions (not statements) in code?  Or the output from print(), the input(prompt) prompt, and the user input in response to the prompt?  In Idle Shell, user input is fixed at black on white (unless syntax colored), while stdout (and stderr) ouput can be colored (and are by default).  If you write your own GUI (for instance with tkinter), you can display different sorts of text how you want.

Answer (score 0):

For coloring terminal output, look at the `xtermcolor` package (https://github.com/broadinstitute/xtermcolor). I think the way this works is by adding special characters setting your terminal color, see [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). It should in principle be possible for bold and underline.

**EDIT :** I don't know if xtermcolor works with WingIDE...